# Program won't accept input for first search term

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that includes a method to search for a song in an array of songs. Below is the code for this particular section that's giving me trouble. The `kybd` has already been initiated, and below is the code for the section, using the `searchSong()` method in my class.

```
    System.out.println("To search for a song, enter the following:");
    System.out.print("Title: ");
    searchT = kybd.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Author: ");
    searchAu = kybd.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Interpreter: ");
    searchI = kybd.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Album: ");
    searchAl = kybd.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Found this:"+'\n'+lib.searchSong(searchT, searchAl, searchAu, searchI));
```

When I run the program, it prints "Title" but doesn't let me enter the search term, it just skips straight to "Author." Below is the output I get.

> To search for a song, enter the following:
>   Title: Author: **search**
>   Interpreter:  **search**
>   Album:  **search**

Can someone explain to me why this might be happening, and maybe how to fix it? I've checked and double checked my code and I can't figure it out.

**Solved!** I was using `nextInt()` for another method previously in the program. I took the advice in the question @Rohit Jain suggested and used a blank `nextLine()` before this section of code, and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your complete code? It is not clear what you did before.

Comment: How do you initialize the `kybd` object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skipping nextLine() after use nextInt()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint)

Comment: It seems like you have used `Scanner#nextInt()` somewhere before that code. Check the post above. It addresses the same issue.

Comment: You're going to have to show how you initialize `kybd` or the code before the one you've posted.

Comment: @RohitJain I have a feeling you're right or at least it's a similar problem...

Comment: @ChrisThompson. Yeah, it's quite a general issue. Happens with beginners.

Comment: @RohitJain You were right, I used nextInt previously in my program. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.print("Title: ");` should be replaced by `System.out.println("Title: ");`

I am assuming that

```
Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
```

since i see `kybd.nextLine()` method

Actually, the input is not getting skipped, just that `Title:` and `Author:` getting printed next to each other because of `print` instead of `println`. Did you try typing text and hitting enter? I am sure you will be allowed to type and enter text twice

Comment: His problem is that his code is skipping the input. How does your fix change that?

Comment: _When I run the program, it prints "Title" but doesn't let me enter the search term, it just skips straight to "Author."_

Comment: The problem is not about printing newline. It's about not reading input for one variable, and moving to another directly.

Comment: I've tried, and it does skip "Title" and my input gets assigned to "Author".

Comment: @sanbhat I don't doubt it. It should work with `print()` as well. There's something OP isn't showing. Your answer is incorrect for handling OP's problem. `println()` over `print()` does nothing to prevent skipping input.

Comment: @sanbhat Was the `nextInt()` finally.